# Why is knitr producing blurred images in pdfs?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

OK, this is driving me nuts. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<simulations, fig.cap = "Simulation results. $b$ = benefit of being helped. $n$ = group size.", fig.align = "center", fig.width = 6, fig.height = 4,  out.width='6in', out.height='4in', dev = 'quartz_pdf', dev.args = list(antialias=FALSE), echo=FALSE>>=


tmp <- structure(list(memory = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30), G = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10), b = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14), gsize = c(12, 
14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 12, 14), GR_wins = c(0.2, 
0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0), Condition = c("m = t = 30, G = 10", 
"m = t = 30, G = 10", "m = t = 30, G = 10", "m = t = 30, G = 10", 
"m = t = 30, G = 10", "m = t = 30, G = 10", "m = t = 30, G = 10", 
"m = t = 30, G = 10", "m = t = 30, G = 10", "m = t = 30, G = 10", 
"m = t = 30, G = 10", "m = t = 30, G = 10"), grwc = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("[0,0.1]", 
"(0.1,0.2]", "(0.2,0.3]", "(0.3,0.4]", "(0.4,0.5]", "(0.5,0.6]", 
"(0.6,0.7]", "(0.7,0.8]", "(0.8,0.9]", "(0.9,1]"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("memory", 
"G", "b", "gsize", "GR_wins", "Condition", "grwc"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("memory", 
"G", "b"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:9, 10:11), group_sizes = c(10L, 
2L), biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(memory = c(30, 
30), G = c(10, 10), b = c(12, 14)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("memory", 
"G", "b"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("memory", "G", "b")))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tmp, aes(gsize, b, fill = grwc)) + geom_raster()

@


\end{document}
```

When I run the code chunk in the command line, I get a picture like:

[image: nice clear output]

But when I compile it using xelatex, by hitting the knit button in RStudio, I get this horrible thing:
[image: blurred foobared output]

I've tried messing with out.width, fig.width, antialiasing in dev.args to the quartz driver, different drivers... can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it, though not sure how, simply by going into the `figure` subdirectory and deleting the relevant figures, which were being cached. After that, using `dev="png"` gave me an OK result.